# ImportError with ffi_closure_alloc and LIBFFI_CLOSURE_7.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conda

I am trying to run tensorflow using conda in a virtual environment.
These are the steps I took:

1. I created a new conda environment using **conda create --name tf python=3.9**
2. I activated the environment using

   ```
   conda activate tf
   ```
3. I made sure cuda and cuDNN were installed

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2.2 cudnn=8.1.0
   ```
4. I configured the system path

   ```
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/
   ```
5. I automated it

   ```
   mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d
   echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/' > $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh
   ```
6. I made sure to install tensorflow

   ```
   pip install tensorflow==2.11.*
   ```
7. Then I tried to verify the install

```
    python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

This is is where I encounter an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sbrent/research/Oman/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/home/sbrent/research/Oman/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: ffi_closure_alloc, version LIBFFI_CLOSURE_7.0
```

Honestly, I have no idea how to fix this, so any guidance would be appreciated.

I listed what I tried in the statement above

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: sudo nano setup.py

Step 2: Go to the following function:

```
    def build_extensions(self):
    self.srcdir = sysconfig.get_config_var('srcdir')
```

Step 3: Add the following line below:

```
    self.srcdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

This worked for us!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to launch system jupyter-notebook which is not compatible with your conda environment.

Install jupyter-notebook inside your conda environment by running

```
pip3 install jupyter
```